# array of custom class not serializing in a server side DTO in web API controller function

Tags: c#, arrays, serialization, asp.net-web-api

my client side sends in an array,**claimSaveLines**, of custom type which is a part of a DTO, as shown in the image

[image]

this object is received at the server side but properties of this array are not serialized.They just contains the default value, as shown in the image below.

[image]

i tried adding [Serializable] it didn't helped.

Comment: just a thought doesn't the case matter here  ???

Comment: no it doesn't. matter .

Comment: Do you have any attributes on any of your properties? What types are Charge and cptCode ?

Comment: are the other properties of containing object transmitted/received correctly or is the array the only thing that the server side object contains?

Comment: No attributes are used

Comment: what about claimEditInd, i think all are not getting serialised rest are default values hence looking like getting serilalized

Comment: are you sure the other properties are really getting populated in that array? Looks like they are default values. Post your DTO object code.

Comment: No attributes are used

Comment: Other properties are getting populated even the arrays of type string. Only array of type custom arent

Comment: if i see charge is sent as string but , here it is type of int hence taking default as 0, please recheck the data types of properties

Comment: i just checked with hard coded integers. its still not working. CPT code is a string which is also null. every thing contains the default values